# How to dynamically get the value from on change of input text field in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the value of the input field if any change(delete,create,modify) happens on the input hidden field(name attribute = ./links/item0/./locationPath) and make an ajax request. But the problem is I don't know how many foundation-autocomplete and how many input hidden fields. It will be created at runtime.

It may be one to upto 20 items. But the name attribute follows the pattern ./links/item{Number}/./locationPath. for example1, ./links/item0/./locationPath, example2, ./links/item2/./locationPath, example, ./links/item2/./locationPath etc., I tried to change events but it is not working. Is there any other way we can write the input value dynamically (The value of the name attribute comes to know runtime)?

I tried with regex to match input field like below but it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Listen for changes to input fields with matching name pattern
  $('input[name^="./links/item"][name$="/./locationPath"]').on('input', function() {

    // Get the value of the changed input field
    var changedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(changedValue);
    // Make an AJAX request with the retrieved value

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<foundation-autocomplete class="coral-Form-field acer-mon" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" required="" pickersrc="/mnt/overlay/granite/ui/content/coral/foundation/form/pathfield/picker.html?_charset_=utf-8&amp;path={value}&amp;root=%2fcontent%2ftoryburch&amp;filter=hierarchyNotFile&amp;selectionCount=single"
  labelledby="label_c373f01c-793f-49e5-a5de-f1605a716471" data-foundation-validation="acer-mon-validator">
  <coral-taglist foundation-autocomplete-value="" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" class="coral3-TagList" aria-disabled="false" role="grid" aria-live="off" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false">
    <coral-tag class="coral3-Tag coral3-Tag--large" closable="" value="/model/protection" role="row" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="coral-id-1465">
      <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" value="/model/protection">
    </coral-tag>
  </coral-taglist>
</foundation-autocomplete>

<foundation-autocomplete class="coral-Form-field acer-mon" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" required="" pickersrc="/mnt/overlay/granite/ui/content/coral/foundation/form/pathfield/picker.html?_charset_=utf-8&amp;path={value}&amp;root=%2fcontent%2ftoryburch&amp;filter=hierarchyNotFile&amp;selectionCount=single"
  labelledby="label_c373f01c-793f-49e5-a5de-f1605a716471" data-foundation-validation="acer-mon-validator">
  <coral-taglist foundation-autocomplete-value="" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" class="coral3-TagList" aria-disabled="false" role="grid" aria-live="off" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false">
    <coral-tag class="coral3-Tag coral3-Tag--large" closable="" value="/model/head" role="row" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="coral-id-1465">
      <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" value="/model/head">
    </coral-tag>
  </coral-taglist>
</foundation-autocomplete>

<foundation-autocomplete>
  ...
</foundation-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to be a [mcve] with relevant HTML and frameworks

Comment: `input field if any change(delete,create,modify) ` : since input fileds are hidden your code `on('input', function() {` will not work. Please clear the scenario

Comment: There is a event that will modify the input hidden field value when there is change happened on coral-tag class="coral3-Tag coral3-Tag--large".

Answer (score 0):

Since the `input` event is fired only when the user interacts with the input control, here it isn't useful with an hidden element.

While the event you talked about that is expected to change those values on its own, is supposed to operate changing the `value` attibute of the element object via js.

You need to intercept those changes even if they don't come straight from a user interaction.

A solution that will safely better approach this need might be using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Here in this demo I show how to attach a MutationObserver to all those hidden input elements and how it will be triggered when changing the value of the very first input element every second mimicking your event.

```js
//the function that will be called by the MutationObserver
const onMutationHandler = (target) => {
  console.log(`${Date.now()} The value was just changed: `, target.value);
};

//create a MutationObserver that will call onMutationHandler when the value attriburte gets set
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'value') {
      onMutationHandler(mutation.target);
    }
  });
});

//attach the mutation observer to all the hidden inputs selected with your criteria
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="./links/item"][name$="/./locationPath"]');
inputs.forEach(input => {
  observer.observe(input, {attributes: true});
});

//Change every second the value of the very first hidden input in the list
//mimicking your event expected to change that value on its own
setInterval(() => {
  inputs[0].value = 'eventchangedvalue!';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<foundation-autocomplete class="coral-Form-field acer-mon" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" required="" pickersrc="/mnt/overlay/granite/ui/content/coral/foundation/form/pathfield/picker.html?_charset_=utf-8&amp;path={value}&amp;root=%2fcontent%2ftoryburch&amp;filter=hierarchyNotFile&amp;selectionCount=single"
  labelledby="label_c373f01c-793f-49e5-a5de-f1605a716471" data-foundation-validation="acer-mon-validator">
  <coral-taglist foundation-autocomplete-value="" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" class="coral3-TagList" aria-disabled="false" role="grid" aria-live="off" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false">
    <coral-tag class="coral3-Tag coral3-Tag--large" closable="" value="/model/protection" role="row" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="coral-id-1465">
      <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./links/item0/./locationPath" value="/model/protection">
    </coral-tag>
  </coral-taglist>
</foundation-autocomplete>

<foundation-autocomplete class="coral-Form-field acer-mon" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" required="" pickersrc="/mnt/overlay/granite/ui/content/coral/foundation/form/pathfield/picker.html?_charset_=utf-8&amp;path={value}&amp;root=%2fcontent%2ftoryburch&amp;filter=hierarchyNotFile&amp;selectionCount=single"
  labelledby="label_c373f01c-793f-49e5-a5de-f1605a716471" data-foundation-validation="acer-mon-validator">
  <coral-taglist foundation-autocomplete-value="" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" class="coral3-TagList" aria-disabled="false" role="grid" aria-live="off" aria-atomic="false" aria-relevant="additions" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false">
    <coral-tag class="coral3-Tag coral3-Tag--large" closable="" value="/model/head" role="row" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="coral-id-1465">
      <input handle="input" type="hidden" name="./links/item1/./locationPath" value="/model/head">
    </coral-tag>
  </coral-taglist>
</foundation-autocomplete>

<foundation-autocomplete>
  ...
</foundation-autocomplete>
```